# How to read and temporarily store text from a text box on a web page

Tags: tosca

I am very new to TOSCA and I don't have a lot of help around me for it, online searches do not seem to answer my question either.

I have scanned a basket page for a website and wish to create a loop to increase the quantity of a single product, but I can't seem to be able to read the quantity already in there, only change it. Is there a way to do this?

I am fine with conditions and loops its just this part of extracting the value from the text box.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get the value from a text box by using the action mode buffer.
Here is the according section of [the manual](https://support.tricentis.com/community/manuals_detail.do?lang=en&version=11.0.0&url=tbox/action_modes.htm).

Comment: Ahh thank you, I was looking at setting buffers instead of using the action mode buffer. Many thanks!